# Editing shared preference in other activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-context

how can I edit value of sharedPreference from other Activity. I try this codes by I'm getting an error on the context part.

```
if(stars == 2){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  scorepref.edit();
    editor.putInt("keyhelloworld", stars);
    editor.commit();
    Intent fromHW = new Intent(HelloWorldGameActivity.this, LessonActivity.class);
    startActivity(fromHW);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.
Pass context from first activity.

To call Shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To call editor

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences as follows. Since sharedpreferences is persistent, you can use the same implementation anywhere in your application to access it.

```
SharedPreference sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("key", value).apply();
```